# почему webstorm и typescript ругаются на получаение геттера написаного под pinia

Tags: typescript, vue3, webstorm, vite

У меня есть хранилище на pinia которое выглядит так

```
export const useLanguage = defineStore<string, { current: string }>({
  id: 'language',
  state: () => ({
    current: 'en',
  }),
  getters: {
    currentLanguage: (state): ILanguage =>
      supportedLanguages.get(state.current) as ILanguage,
  },
  persist: true,
})
```

Я хочу получить реактивное свойство следующим образов

```
const { currentLanguage } = storeToRefs(useLanguage())
```

Однако typescript/webstorm ругаются на меня

> Volar: Property 'currentLanguage' does not exist on type 'StoreToRefs >'.

Хотя если принудительно собрать код то все работает, поэтому ошибка в typescript/webstorm
Так же возможно ошибка в моем vite конфиге
Можете подсказать как решить или в какую сторону копать